# Webscrape from webpage list with no clear delimiters in R

Tags: r, parsing, web-scraping

Learning to webscrape in R from a list of contacts on this webpage:https://ern-euro-nmd.eu/board-members/

There are 65 rows (contacts) and should be 3 columns of associated details (Name, institution, and location). Here is a copy/paste of one row of data from the webpage:
Adriano Chio
Azienda Ospedaliero Universitaria Città della Salute e della Scienza
Italy

My current approach lumps all the details into one column. How can I split the data into 3 columns.

There is only white space apparently between these details on the webpage. Not sure what to do.

#Below is my R code:

```
EURONMD_KOLs<- read_html("https://ern-euro-nmd.eu/board-members/") %>%
  html_nodes(".detailsListing")%>%
  html_text()

EURONMD_KOLs

EURONMD_KOLs_table<-data.frame(EURONMD_KOLs)
```

#end of R code

My resulting table lumps everything into one column.  I need to separate reach row of data into 3 columns. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove leading and lagging new line character from the text, split on `'\n'` and create a 3-column dataframe.

```
library(rvest)

read_html("https://ern-euro-nmd.eu/board-members/") %>%
  html_nodes(".detailsListing")%>%
  html_text() %>%
  trimws() %>%
  strsplit('\n+') %>%
  do.call(rbind, .) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames(c('Name', 'institution', 'location')) -> result

head(result)

#                    Name                                                          institution    location
#1           Adriano Chio Azienda Ospedaliero Universitaria Città della Salute e della Scienza       Italy
#2     Alessandra Ferlini                                         University Hospital St. Anna       Italy
#3      Andrés Nascimento                   Hospital Sant Juan de Déu Universidad de Barcelona       Spain
#4          Angela Kaindl                                 Charité - Universitätsmedizin Berlin     Germany
#5 Anna Kostera-Pruszczyk                                  SPCSK, Medical University of Warsaw      Poland
#6    Anneke van der Kooi                                              Academic Medical Centre Netherlands
```

Comment: Ronak, That hit the nail right on the head! Thanks so much.